# how to resolve g++ warning with -std=c++11: ‘auto_ptr’ is deprecated

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

Trying out `-std=c++11` with the `g++` compiler, I got lots of

```
warning: ‘auto_ptr’ is deprecated (declared at 
/usr/include/c++/4.8/backward/auto_ptr.h:87) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
```

What should I use instead of `auto_ptr`? Please give an informative link or a complete answer.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Pragmas.html i.e. you can use #pragma GCC diagnostic warning "-Wdeprecated-declarations"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `std::unique_ptr` instead of `std::auto_ptr`

And if you copied `auto_ptr`, you have to `std::move` the `unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

> *"What should I use instead of `auto_ptr`?"*

The class representing `std::auto_ptr<>`'s behavior most closely is [`std::unique_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).